# How to sort 1 Woocommerce Order's products by product description in WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently using WP All Export Pro and using WP_Query to pull only the last Woocommerce order completed. This is the code:

function example_get_those_ids($post_type = 'post', $number_of_posts = 5, $order = 'ASC', $post_status = 'publish', $order_by = 'ID') {

```
$query = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'numberposts' => $number_of_posts,
        'order' => $order,
        'orderby' => $order_by,
        'post_status' => $post_status,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    )
);

return ( !empty($query) ) ? $query : array();
```

}

And then running this in the query.

'post_type' => 'shop_order', 'post_status' => 'wc_completed', 'post__in' => example_get_those_ids('shop_order', '1', 'DESC', 'wc_completed')

I was wondering how I can then go ahead and sort the products in that query by product description or a custom product field if possible.

Thank you.